# Create a flag in a left join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am trying to create a new column (a sort of identifier flag) for the "Null" rows resulting of my following left join :

```
with CTE (...) as (
... unrelated code
) select * from CTE

left join (select columnID from table1) Pu
on CTE.columnID = Pu.columnID

left join (select case when bz.column2 is null then 'null test is working' else columnID2, column2 end FROM table2) Bz
ON CTE.columnID2 = Bz.columnID2
```

This code is working properly when I don't try to use a 'case when'. Actually, you could very well ignore the first left join.

My purpose would be to be able **test the left join result** while doing it, and act depending on the result :

If the left join result give **a null row : creation of a flag column** for the row,

If the left join result give **a normal row : the left join is done normally**, and the flag column is empty (as I suspect it cant be un existent).

I'd be glad if you could give me a hand!

EDIT : tables example:

```
CTE
| columnID | columnID2 | InformationsCTE | 
|    ab    |    mp     |    randominfo1  |
|    ac    |    ma     |    randominfo2  |
|    ae    |    me     |    randominfo3  |
|    ad    |    mb     |    randominfo4  |

table2
| columnID2 | InformationsTable2  | 
|    mp     |     randominfo5     |
|    ma     |     randominfo6     |
|    me     |     randominfo7     |
```

Result after the second left join :

```
new CTE
| columnID | columnID2 | InformationsCTE |  InformationsTable2|  FLAG |
|    ab    |    mp     |    randominfo1  |     randominfo5    |   OK  |
|    ac    |    ma     |    randominfo2  |     randominfo6    |   OK  |
|    ae    |    me     |    randominfo3  |     randominfo7    |   OK  |
|    ad    |    mb     |    randominfo4  |        NULL        |   NOK |
```

Comment: Reflecting on my answer, I'm starting to doubt I've completely understood your goal. The value of ColumnID2 will never be null if you've used a Left join, rendering the ISNULL a bit pointless. I'm also not convinced your `CASE` statement is valid. Can you explain a bit more about what you want to achieve? Maybe add a couple of line of example data?

Comment: Please act on [mcve]. PS Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Aside from clarifying your question as it is now, please explain an example of what you actually want to accomplish via flags without mentioning flags, because this flag business seems misconceived & you don't seem to understand left join. Be very clear about what the input can look like.

Comment: @BarryPiccinni When a left join condition is not just an equality of columns, an output right table column can be null from being input rather than from null-extending an unmatched left table row. Not that the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would it not be more practical to `SELECT` this column, use the `ISNULL` operator and just use a straightforward `LEFT JOIN`? I feel like you're over-complicating it a bit.

Something like:

```
with CTE (...) as (
... unrelated code
) 

SELECT CTE.*, NVL(bz.InformationsTable2, 'TEST OK')
FROM CTE
LEFT JOIN table2 Bz ON CTE.columnID2 = Bz.columnID2
```

**EDIT**: Based on your example table, if you join on the ID, then use NVL on the other column, it should work for you.

Here is an example I prepared for a previous question: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a37ede/2)

*Example was build in mysql, so beware syntax, but logically it works the same way*

Answer (score 3):

Just use

T-SQL:

```
SELECT ISNULL(Column_to_check,'flag') FROM SomeTable
```

PL/SQL:

```
SELECT NVL(Column_to_check,'flag') FROM SomeTable
```

Also use NVL2 as below if you want to return other value from the Column_to_check:

```
NVL2(Column_to_check, value_if_NOT_null, value_if_null )
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. my problem is more be able to test if the result of my join is null. if it is : a new column (the flag to identify the null) is created during/after the join. if it is not, the join would do it works as usual..

Answer (score 2):

Why the joins? It seems you only want to look up data in other table, for which you'd use `EXISTS` or `IN`:

```
with cte (...) as (
... unrelated code
)
select 
  cte.*,
  case when columnid in (select columnid from table1) then 'okay' else 'fail' end as test1,
  case when columnid2 in (select columnid2 from table2) then 'okay' else 'fail' end as test2
from cte;
```

Comment: thank you for your help. well the original purpose is to join all of the data of the three tables. or more likely, add some informations from the table1 and table2 to the CTE table. my joins were able to do it. but I need to add a flag column, to be able to identify the rows (in the final table, result of the request) that had no match in the left join with the table2.

Comment: Ah, so it's not only about the flag, but also about more columns. Well, you see from the IDs whether a match was found: `select cte.*, pu.*, case when pu.columnid is null then 'fail' else 'okay' end as pu_check ...`.

Comment: the first left join was only for informations, it is not really related to my problem. I am trying to do a left join between CTE and table2, if the result of the join is null : a new column is created (to flag the row), if not, the join is done normally

Comment: So the solution given in my second comment was what you needed. I wonder why you didn't apply it right away. Only because you had to change pu.columnid to bz.columnid2?

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your answer, thank you again for your help